# I am trying to display a choropleth map in jupyter notebook however nothing is showing up

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, choropleth

I have one dataset with state and counts.
And I have imported the geojson of UK cities into UK_city. I have linked the two (json and dataset with the country id (column 'id'). The simplified dataset is:

This is my dataset with the count of vehicle crime in each city

[image]

I have written this code with aim to plot the count on each city of the country, However, no error is being displayed neither any map is showing up.

[image]

I have tried solutions like using firefox to display it but nothing seems to work.

I have downloaded the geojson from here:
https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::wards-dec-2015-full-extent-boundaries-in-gb/explore?location=55.081966%2C-3.262780%2C6.00

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! Pictures of code or data are not helpful and will oftentimes lead to unanswered questions. I see that you've provided a link to the real geojson data. You need to provide data or similar data for the data frame you use in your code. For this type of plot, the literal words and structure make a big difference. When you add code to your questions, it's really important to add it as code that can be copied and pasted like text. (No pictures of words...ever.)

Comment: The geojson file you presented has no entries to associate with user data. You need to either modify the user data or find a geojson file that matches the user data. And the geojson you presented has about 8000 lines, so it requires acquisition time. So, I think you need to increase the size of the drawing unit or take some other action.